# Result of query has a [Function] as value

Tags: sql, node.js, subquery, firebird, node-firebird

I'm running a SQL statement and it has a sub select. But after running, the result field has a [Function] value.

Do I doing something wrong?
My SQL is something like it:

```
SELECT
    product.CODE
    , (SELECT LIST(item.size, '/') FROM ITEMS item WHERE item.CODE = product.CODE) AS SIZES
FROM
    PRODUCTS product
WHERE
    product.CODE = '98015';
```

But the result is:

| CODE | SIZES |
| --- | --- |
| 98015 | [Function] |

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, Did you define the 'List' function ? I don't see it as an aggregate function in the MySQL documentation. Why not  joining tables instead?

Comment: Please show the code you use to execute and retrieve the result. Or at least, given you added node-firebird to the title, I assume you have this problem when executing the query from node.js. Also include sample DDL and data.

Comment: @jesicadev18 The OP is using Firebird, not MySQL. Firebird's `LIST` is similar to MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: A possible cause might be the fact that `LIST` returns `blob sub_type text`, which could possibly lead to node-firebird applying a different form of retrieval (I don't know node-firebird, so can't really help with that, maybe you can find relevant info on https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird). You could also try explicitly casting to a `varchar` of sufficient size.

Comment: \o/ @MarkRotteveel you was right!! The node-firebird returns a blob type and as you suggested I have did the cast to VARCHAR and it worked!

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Consider posting your fixed code as an answer, it might help others as well.

Comment: @MarcelZanluca node-js documents a special approach for BLOB's at https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird  Casting to VARCHAR has a limitation of maximum data length

Comment: @MarcelZanluca can u try turning `Firebird` from `var` to `const` and see if you would have the same problems as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623556/ ?

Comment: @Arioch'The `var` vs `const` is not relevant here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it is not relevant here, but might be relevant for another topic. I try to bring node-js users together so they can help each other. If there came a stream of node-js+Firebird users it would be good to bring them together.

Comment: @Arioch'The Just random guessing doesn't help and only serves to sow confusion. `const` means that the reference can't reassigned, while `var` can be reassigned and restricts the scope to the enclosing function (instead of the immediately enclosing scope).